# Argument type mismatch (void*)

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, casting

So I'm trying to use pthread_create but I'm getting

```
error: argument of type ‘void* (server::)(void*)’ does not match ‘void* (*)(void*)’
```

The class is defined as follows:

```
class server : public AL::ALModule
{
  public:
  server(boost::shared_ptr<AL::ALBroker> pBroker, const std::string& pName);
  ....
  void *ThreadMain(void *arg);               
}
```

};

And here's the function where I'm calling pthread from:

```
int server::listen() {

TCPServerSocket servSock(6004);
...

for (;;) {     

  clntSock = servSock.accept();
  ...
  pthread_t threadID;         
  pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, this->ThreadMain,(void *) clntSock);
  ...
  }
}
```

How do I cast ThreadMain from server:: to * ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ThreadMain` is a member function. If you cast it, it won't do what you think it will. You should make the function `static` and pass `this` as an argument if it needs to access class attributes

Comment: If it doesn't need to access member attributes, just make `ThreadMain` static and it should work.

Comment: @agbinfo While trying to pass this as an argument, I get: invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)(server&)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’

Comment: Marwan, I see that you accepted an answer that didn't require access to `this` so I'll assume you didn't need it. If you do let me know and I'll add an answer that can access the object.

Comment: @agbinfo I'm sure your answer would be helpful others with similar problems who do require access to member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void *ThreadMain(void* arg)
```

should be

```
static void ThreadMain(void* arg)
```

and the invocation:

```
pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, &(server::ThreadMain), (void *) clntSock);
```

The thread you're creating has no way of knowing what your `this` pointer is; C++ is trying to protect you from this fact by making you acknowledge that `ThreadMain` is static and can't access non-static properties.

The problem with using `&(this->anyFunc)` is that `this` has no actual reference to its methods if they're not function pointers or virtual, nor does the method itself have any reference to a corresponding `this` unless it's provided by the caller (implicitly).

Comment: Yep.  The first is a function prototype and the second is a pointer to a void function.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it converted to server::* which still gives me an error:

cannot convert ‘void* (server::*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the use of static functions because I want to access other members of the class. Is there any other way to overcome this?

Comment: Honestly, I know nothing about a `pthread`; I always used the WinAPI CreateThread.  If I was doing that, there would be a parameter that I could pass to the thread on creation, and that would be the `this` in your question.  Essentially, there's no way to make C++ understand that the thread procedure is a method of a particular object without modifying the prototype of `pthread_create`, and the best you can do is start the thread as a static function and proceed to call the object method from there.